# external_app_launcher redirects to playstore

Tags: flutter

So i'm trying to open an app if it is already available in the device. but this code is not working as it should, even though the app is installed in my device it's still redirecting to playstore without opening the App. I have provided the correct package name also

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Color containerColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () async {
                  await LaunchApp.openApp(
                    androidPackageName: 'com.truecaller' 
                    // openStore: false
                  );
                  // Enter thr package name of the App you want to open and for iOS add the URLscheme to the Info.plist file.
                  // The second arguments decide wether the app redirects PlayStore or AppStore.
                  // For testing purpose you can enter com.instagram.android
                },
                child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Open",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ))),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add the following line inside the  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

it worked for me :-)